# check_nt and check_nrpe give error for shared object file

Tags: plugins, shared, nagios

I recompiled nagios with cygwin so now I have a nagios that works in Windows. The problem is I cannot get anything from NSClient or NRPE. I also recompiled the plugins with the command so now I have "check_nt.exe" and "check_nrpe.exe". I installed NSClient++ to my client.

When I run the following commands from the command line everything seems to be working fine.

```
ls\plugins>check_nrpe.exe -H 10.0.0.73
I (0.3.9.328 2011-08-16) seem to be doing fine...

ls\plugins>check_nt.exe -H 10.0.0.73 -v CLIENTVERSION -p 12489 -s test
NSClient++ 0.3.9.328 2011-08-16
```

Unfortunately I am starting nagios, nagios is working fine but I cannot get anything from the client. The plugin output is:

```
plugin_output=(Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)
```

In my nagios-stderr.log file it gives the following error:

```
/plugins/check_nrpe.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/plugins/check_nt.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My services.cfg file:

```
define service{
use  generic-service
hostgroup_name   windows-comps
service_description NSClient++ Version
check_command    check_nt!CLIENTVERSION
}
```

My commands.cfg file:

```
define command{
command_name check_nrpe
command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
define command{
command_name check_nt
command_line $USER1$/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 12489 -s test -v $ARG1$ $ARG2$
}
```

Do you have any idea about what causes this and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I made it. If there is another one who encounters the same problem, here is the solution.

Do not install nagios service with user credentials. I am running the service as Local System Account and now eveything is working.  ;)